# Cursors Sub Query - An aggregate may not appear UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, aggregate-functions, dynamic-sql

I'm very close to gaining understanding how cursors work and using them for small tasks.

i get the following error.

`An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement`

I'm guessing my issue here is the `UPDATE` and the `SELECT` stamement using an aggregate function such as `MAX`, but i'm finding it difficult to re-work my quoted statement here. from other posts i've read, its said to use a sub-query?

Base table is built using..

```
SELECT
      QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id)) AS [DB_Schema],
      QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) AS [TableName],
      SUM(sPTN.Rows) AS [Row_Count]
INTO ##tmpRowCount2
FROM 
      sys.objects AS sOBJ
      INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS sPTN
            ON sOBJ.object_id = sPTN.object_id
WHERE
      sOBJ.type = 'U'
      AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
      AND index_id < 2
GROUP BY 
      sOBJ.schema_id
      , sOBJ.name
ORDER BY [Row_Count]
GO

ALTER TABLE ##tmpRowCount2 ADD updated_timestamp datetime NULL;

DECLARE @Row_Count int
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @TableName as VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @DB_Schema as VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @updated_timestamp as DATETIME

DECLARE tablenamefromcursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TableName, Row_Count, DB_Schema
FROM ##tmpRowCount2
        
OPEN tablenamefromcursor

FETCH NEXT FROM tablenamefromcursor INTO  @TableName, @Row_Count, @DB_Schema
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'UPDATE ##tmpRowCount2  SET updated_timestamp = ' + 
            '(SELECT MAX([updated_timestamp]) FROM ' + @DB_Schema + '.' + @TableName + 
            ') WHERE TableName = ''' + @TableName + ''''
        select @sql
        EXEC(@sql)
        FETCH NEXT FROM tablenamefromcursor INTO  @TableName, @Row_Count, @DB_Schema
    END

CLOSE tablenamefromcursor
DEALLOCATE tablenamefromcursor
```

i'm now getting the following errors

[image: SELECT statements]
[image: more errors]

Comment: Aside... why `varchar(256)`? Object names (tables, views, columns, etc.) are typically defined as `sysname`, which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128) not null`.

Comment: Aside?Do you feel this is what is causing the issue of getting a MAX date from another table?

Comment: I do not. I'm bringing attention to the choice of data types. More likely this error is due to the way the dynamic SQL is being constructed - it makes big assumptions that schema names and table names are going to be valid SQL tokens and makes no effort to use `QUOTENAME()` to protect against multi-word names or other things that would be invalid tokens.

Comment: the table which the code is trying to update is built using the following

Comment: code edited above

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9aa37d6f9cb258c91fdc0d3b55e4266d You should select @sql and run the code

Comment: Great work on the Fiddle and thanks, it helped try and diagnose the problem at least, i have tried moving the parathesis in the iteration. I can run one of these select statements once manually, but if i try it again on another table i get the errors

Comment: post editited to show latest code and errors

Comment: Using a cursor to update a global temp table is a pretty clear indication that the design of this system went down a sketchy path.

Answer (score -1):

Code editied above and i can confirm it works, by debugging with select @sql iwas able to parse the statement and edit the syntax unitl it worked by getting the parethesis and quotes in the right order

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).